# Error binding JNA to Xamarin.Android Binding library

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, jna

I am trying to bind JNA-3.0.9 jar to binding library as EmbeddedReferenceJar as it is required by one of the other JARs i am using.

I am facing the error binding a jna-3.0.9 jar file. The error message is  :

> Error  CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'IFromNativeConverter.NativeType()' and 'IToNativeConverter.NativeType()'    EDCBinding1 ****\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sun.Jna.ITypeConverter.cs  108 Active

Is it really required to bind JNA jar seperately? or is it already part of Microsoft OpenJDK?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: According to your error message,I suggest you can try to bind jar seperately, about binding a .JAR, please take a look:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar

Comment: I am trying to bind jar seperately only.

Comment: Anything update?

Comment: Hi everybody, Does anyone solved the problem, because I have exactly the same problem

Comment: Was this issue resolve, please help facing the same issue